# Is it possible to create a Cortana Channel on Azure Bot Service programmatically

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cli, azure-bot-service

In [MSFT DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest), I found I can use az cli to create a channel such as skype, FB, ...etc but I didn't see anything regarded to Cortana.

I am wondering if there is any way to create a Cortana Channel programmatically. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time.  If you create an issue https://feedback.azure.com/forums/562027-azure-bot-service it might get attention.